# Angular 2 Material Autocomplete - get (valid) selected item

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

I want the selected value of the Angular Material AutoComplete to be stored to a variable in the component.

I can't use [(ngModel)] on < input > because, it will also allow every input by the user.

A further restriction is my usage of the

```
(onSelectionChange)="onFilterChange($event)"
```

EventEmitter, which I need.

The documentation is pretty insufficient:
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api

Is there a good way to get the selected value (and ONLY selectable values!) from the autocomplete Component?

I thought about using the "activeOption" property, but the API doesn't describe how to use it.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to read through [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3334)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `optionSelected` event handler

```
(optionSelected)="itemSelected($event)"
```

and then in your component

```
  itemSelected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    console.log("Selected item", event.option.value);
  }
```

Comment: What about clearing input if there is not selected value? In this case I try to use input's `blur()` event, but in that case I cannot access the autocomplete value (if selected or not). Any idea?